NextJS unable to import and apply font
So I got this static html template which I'm currently converting to next/react.
No matter what I do, I can't seem to apply a google font (Rajdhani) on the body, only to the main tag with the layout being messed up. When changing the monospace attribute in the globals.css it shows a times new roman style font, so it does something, but not what I want it to.
I'm using nextjs 14.2.3 with react and tailwind with framer-motion.
The scaling works with monospace applied, but the font is still not being applied.
I've also tried importing via link in the header, without any success. I don't know what to do anymore.
left-layout.js | right-globals.css
As already said, I don't know what to do anymore. I can't seem to get the font working on the body. Only on the main tag, which messes up the whole styling.

A few important things.

To override the base styles on Tailwind. Use the @layer directive. [1]

@layer base {
    body {
        /* your styles */
    }
}


There is a dedicated section on using NextJS's fonts package with tailwind [2]. From what I can see, they are using a approach based on css variable instead of className.

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
 
const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-inter',
})
 
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={`${inter.variable} font-sans`}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}

Also, adding it on the tailwind.config.js file
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-inter)'],
        mono: ['var(--font-roboto-mono)'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}


References:
1: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles
2: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#with-tailwind-css
